# How do you select parent of parent div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom accordion setup using Javascript. Currently using onclick I'm toggling a style to the parent div (currently holding a class of "card" and adding "card-open"). My question is how to I go one div higher and begin manipulating the div with the class "time-steam-event"?

Live Example: http://bit.ly/1rr6zGA

**HTML:**

```
<div class="time-stream-event" id="{entry_id}">
    <div style="background: url({timeline_item_img}) no-repeat center center;" class="event-bg grayscale"></div>
    <div class="card">
        <h3><a href="{title_permalink="/timeline"}">{title}</a></h3>
        <div class="event-year">{timeline_item_date format="%F %Y"}</div>
        <a href="#" class="togglelink"></a>
        <div class="toggle-box">
            <p>{timeline_item_description}</p>
            <div class="employees">Number of Employees</div>
            <div class="employee-count-no"> <i class="ss-icon">&#x1F465;</i> {timeline_item_employees}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="open-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
};

$('.toggle-box').hide();

$('a.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.toggle-box')
    $('.toggle-box').not(elem).hide();
    elem.slideFadeToggle();

    var parent_div = $(this).parent().toggleClass('card-open');

});
```

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('.time-stream-event');`

Comment: Try .parentElement it will get the immediate parent according to your DOM.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("togglelink")[0].parentElement;

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("togglelink")[0].parentElement;`

Thats how it doing using Javascript.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("togglelink")
```

return the array of element which have "togglelink" class. You need to get the the Exact Element. If you have only one element My code is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.closest()` or `.parents()`:

```
var obj= $(this).closest('.time-steam-event');//reference to closest .time-steam-event
```

or

```
var obj= $(this).parents('.time-steam-event');//reference to closest .time-steam-event
```

Comment: So I added the following to the onclick and it doesn't toggle the class ".time-stream-event-open". What am I doing wrong?

'var obj= $(this).closest('.time-steam-event');
 obj.toggleClass('time-steam-event-open');'

Comment: Can You share the problem fiddle.

Comment: @DanLee: would be great if you can create the fiddle with relevant code.

Comment: @DanLee: what is wrong in the fidddle. toggle looks working fine to me on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this:

```
var parent_div = $(this).parent().parent();
```

or:

```
var parent_div = $(this).parent().closest(".time-steam-event");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your div is at the 2nd position in hierarchy (by level) you can use

```
var yourdiv = $(this).parent().parent();
```

Or you can use `.closest()` either

```
var yourdiv = $(this).closest('.time-steam-event');
```